# UWP , What skill Do I need to make the 2 animation?

Tags: xaml, animation, uwp, uwp-xaml, blend

Here is my next project for 2 sensor monitor. I designed a simple UI to display sensor values.

**I need advice about direction of development. Especially Animation.**

Here is my designed UI.
[image]

- Left is normal status. Both Sensor value is good.
- Right is warning status. Right sensor value is too high , I want to add 2 animation on UI.

**Animation [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bN2H.jpg)**

First animation is like this.
[image]

I made this with Blend-VS2017. but Today is my first day with UWP animation ..... **I really worry my skill.**

with Blend, I make like this.... but To continue this animation , it is not good. because This is only 5 second animation. if I repeat this only, it is not beautiful. because At Repeating point, User found animation is repeated.

[image]

**Animation [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYGrT.gif)**

It is background flowing...Red + Orange color.

[image]

I made it with blend, but To repeat it, I have no idea.. I can not copy lot of rectangle.

To make this 2 animation, What class/function do I need ? or should I use a Blend function ?

Before I start the development, I need advice what I should learn....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways you can create these two animations, but given that you just got your hands dirty with Blend, let's keep the solution as simple as possible - expect to do 99% of the work in Blend alone!

**Background animation**

To create a repeatable background animation, all you need to do is to animate your striped background's translate by

> (*The distance between two rectangles* **+** *The height of rectangle*)  **x** `Math.Sqrt(2)`

Assuming the angle of your background is 45 degrees.

So if you define a `32xn` rectangle with a margin of 16, the translate would be `(32 + 16 *2) * 1.414 = 90.5`. Then your background animation would be something like the following

```
<Storyboard x:Name="BackgroundAnimation"
            RepeatBehavior="Forever">
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2"
                     To="-90.5"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)"
                     Storyboard.TargetName="RectGroups"
                     d:IsOptimized="True" />
    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:2"
                     To="-90.5"
                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateY)"
                     Storyboard.TargetName="RectGroups"
                     d:IsOptimized="True" />
</Storyboard>
```

**Circle spreading animation**

This one is even simpler. All you have to do is to duplicate your animation, and delay the start of the second one by **half a second**, given each spreading animation duration is one second.

Have a look at this little [sample](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/UWPAnimations) I just created. Hope you will find it helpful. Good luck!

**Sample result**

[image]

Comment: It's great !   with your code, It make me learn lot of : )  Thank you very much.

Comment: No wonder you are an MVP. I was trying the same for one of my apps. This saved a lot of my time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Am I right: you want to repeat this animations? 
if it is: you can open animation in XAML and set RepeatBehavior="Forever" of your DoubleAnimation or whatever you use.

If I wrong, write what do you want.
It would be better if you show you XAML of your Storyboard.

Comment: Thank you !, I found a way to repeat animation : )  in my animation, There is lot of rectangle or circle, Is there a way to repeat animation from 3 second by 4 second period only ?  because If we repeat with 0-5 second, in repeating, It is not smooth repeating.

Comment: in Animation 2, Is this correct way to make this animation ? Is there any better way ?

Comment: If it's helped you, please mark post as Answer.
You can create a few rectangles and create DoubleAnimations for each.
Then tune repeating for each rectangle.

Comment: Unfortunately, Answer is not enough for me....   with only repeating, To make this animation is not enough...    I need a way to repeat from 2 second by 4 second with 5 second blend animation.  and Is this Animation (2) good way to use rectangle ? with a programming, can we make better animation ? or should we copy lot of rectangle ?? and How to apply the "animation(2)" to background wall of UWP ?